# Which Actor model library/framework for python and Erlang-like?

Tags: python, erlang, actor, python-stackless

I am looking for an easy-to-learn Actor library or framework for Python 2.x. I have tried Candygram and Twisted but I did not like them. I'd like something that will be easy to extend to suppero Greenlet (= stackless python).

- Candygram is too old.
- Twisted is too complicated.
- Gevent: it is unclear if it can support Actors model.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I don't know anything about Candygram, but I thought Twisted was more oriented around networking than around Actor-based concurrency.

Comment: The best Erlang like actors are implemented in Erlang. Do concurrent oriented work in Erlang and left rest of work to python through ports. I would do whole work in Erlang but if someone think that Python is better for any task it is his taste.

Comment: I know a bit of Erlang it rocks, but I'd prefer to use Python.
I need not to to the same thing I do in Erlang in Python, and also not in the same way

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To make actors with [gevent](http://www.gevent.org), use a [Greenlet](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#greenlet-objects) subclass with embedded [gevent.queue.Queue](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.queue.html) instance used as an inbox. To read a message from the inbox, simply [get()](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.queue.html#gevent.queue.Queue.get) from the queue. To send a message to an actor, [put](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.queue.html#gevent.queue.Queue.put) it into that actor's queue.

[Read about subclassing Greenlet here](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#lightweight-pseudothreads).

If you need help with writing the Actor class, feel free to [ask the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/gevent).

Answer (score 15):

Check out [pulsar](http://quantmind.github.io/pulsar/index.html), it is a concurrent framework for python which uses the actor model as source of parallel execution.

Comment: Pulsar seems to be maintained very well, and also supports Python3's `asyncio` functionalities.

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is a bit dated but here is another actor resource for python now:

https://github.com/godaddy/Thespian

Documentation can be found here:

http://godaddy.github.io/Thespian/doc/

**EDIT**:

The primary author of this library has since left GoDaddy and forked the repo:

https://github.com/kquick/Thespian

New docs can be found here:

http://thespianpy.com/doc/

Answer (score 5):

[PARLEY](http://osl.cs.uiuc.edu/parley/) and [Pykka](http://pykka.readthedocs.org) are listed on this [Wikipedia Actor Model page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Actor_libraries_and_frameworks) so you might want to look into one of those.

Pykka seems to be actively developed (1.0.1 released in Dec 2012) whereas PARLEY hasn't had a release since 2007 (and is still listed as beta) . Pykka claims to be insipired by [Akka](http://akka.io/) only in name is not a simply a python port.

Comment: What confuses me is that in Erlang, it's very common for actors to message themselves. In Pykka it's not clear how an object gets a reference of itself.

Comment: Not sure how new this feature is, but Pykka 1.2.0 supports self.actor_ref.  This is explicitly mentioned in the [Proxies section](http://www.pykka.org/en/latest/api/#proxies) of the docs as a way for an actor to "schedule future work" with itself, so I'd imagine that's strongly supported.

Comment: looks like pykka no longer actively developed

Comment: Last commit in March 2019, looks it's still in development. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This [tutorial](http://sdiehl.github.com/gevent-tutorial/) has a simple and working example for actors with gevent. Basically it's exactly as Denis already described.

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at this: https://bitbucket.org/fzzzy/python-actors

It's pretty much a straight clone of the Erlang actor model, with "saved" messages queue, links and everything.